# How to make a ServiceFabric actor go off in the far future

Tags: c#, actor, azure-service-fabric, integer-overflow

So if I have an actor and I use the following line:

```
await RegisterReminderAsync("My Reminder", new byte[0], 
    TimeSpan.FromDays(30), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I can set a reminder to go off in 30 days, with a period of 60 seconds. However, if I try to setup a reminder to go off in 60 days, an exception will be thrown because `RegisterReminderAsync` converts the due data to milliseconds as an unsigned integer (`uint`), which can only hold around 50 days. So, what if I want to set a reminder for a year in the future? Or 10 years?

I could set the reminder to populate a new reminder when the old reminder is called, thereby allowing me to extend the period indefinitely but that seems dirty and not the best implementation we could use. Is there a way to specify how the method should handle the due date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that's how it works today but I opened an issue to use int64 instead: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-services-and-actors-dotnet/issues/13

Comment: That would be great! We could then set times for 584 million years in the future (assuming uint64s anyway). Of course, once Y584M approaches we'll have to worry about wraparound so best not to place too much stock in it ;)